# How can I enrich my bash one-liner to get a default value

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I have in a comprehensive script  this one-liner:

```
grep -P -o "(?s)description\".+>" ./Hlinks.html \
  | grep -P -o "(?s)ISBN[^:]{0,1}: {0,1}[-0-9X]+[ \|]*" \
  | perl -p -e  "s/ISBN[^:]*:*|[\|| ]//g"
  | sed -n "/.*/p;1q"  > ./nISBN.txt
```

Now I would like to get a default output (f.e. "N.A.") when the one-liner outputs nothing. How can I enrich my one-liner to get this wish?

Thanks a lot

Walter

Comment: There are checks you can make on return values at different points in the pipe-line, but this would complicate things hugely. The cheap and cheerful answer is to append `; [ -s ./nISBN.txt ] || echo N.A. >./nISBN.txt`.

Comment: @AFH THanks, but I have now this: It does not work, Have I appened it correctly? `cat $1  | grep -P -o "(?s)ISBN[^:]{0,1}: {0,1}[-0-9X]+[ \|]*"  | perl -p -e  "s/ISBN[^:]*:*|[\|| ]//g" | sed -n "/.*/p;1q"  > ./nISBN.txt; [ -s ./nISBN.txt ] || echo N.A. > ./nISBN.txt` I have forget to say: THe file ./nISBN.txt is always there (an old ISBN form an old task)

Comment: It looks correct, though the original script is not quite the same as in your question. Whether or not `./nISBN.txt` exists previously should not matter - it will always be overwritten. What's not working? Is an empty file not being overwritten with `N.A.`? Or is the file always overwritten, whether empty or not?

Comment: I have modified for testing. (so that I can imput Console characters)I get an empty ./nISBN.txt file with 0 bytes on the dir. No N.A. in it if I enter no ISBN keyword.

Comment: Here I have done it with this corrected oneliner: `cat $1  | grep -P -o "(?s)ISBN[^:]{0,4}: {0,1}[-0-9X]+[ \|]*"  | perl -p -e  "s/ISBN[^:]*:*|[\|| ]//g" | sed -n "/.*/p;1q" > ./nISBN.txt; [ -s ./nISBN.txt ] || echo N.A. > ./nISBN.txt` and wenn I enter f.e. ISBN-13: 23232 I get 23232 in the file: but when I enter INNNN: 34343 I get a empty file. But I would like to get in this case: N.A.

Comment: I've tested your precise string, but with an `echo` command instead of `cat` and it works exactly as you say you want with each of the two strings you cited. All that I can think is that you have one or more blank lines in the output. If so, use `[ $(wc -w < ./nISBN.txt) == 0 ]` as the check. By the way, I never use `cat FileName | ...`: it is always better to use `<file` in the next command.

Comment: @AFH Thanks a lot! I have learnt again a lot.

Comment: I was going to carry on to suggest that a single `sed` command could handle the `grep` and `perl` commands, but your accepted answer is probably neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline can be collapsed into a single perl script, since perl can do everything that grep and sed can do. Something like

```
perl -nE '
    $found = 0;
    if (/description\".+>/ && /ISBN[^:]?:\s*([-0-9X]+[ \|]*)/) {
        $found = 1;
        say $1;
    }
    END {say "N/A" unless $found}
' ./Hlinks.html  > ./nISBN.txt
```

grep is a line-oriented tool, so I'm not sure the `(?s)` is actually doing anything for you.

Taking a step back, you should be using an HTML parser on that data: regular expressions are simply not powerful enough to parse HTML -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/4598162/7552

Comment: thanks, but can you modify your perfect answer so that I can work with an input file rather than the Console imput?

Comment: I don't understand. I provide a filename after the closing single quote. I did add the output redirection.

Comment: Thanks I needes some time to interpret this exact solution :) THANKS A LOT